# Maclaurin's series of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

I'm attempting to express the following function (let $\xi$ be a parameter)

$$f(z) = \dfrac{1}{(1 - 2\xi z + z^2)^2} $$

So far, I have thought about getting the expression for $g(z) = \dfrac{1}{1 - 2\xi z + z^2} $ first, then multiply the series. However, I don't know how to effectively expand this in a neighbor of $0$, as I can only use the expansion $\dfrac{1}{1-a}$ when $|a| < 1$.

Is there any way to expand the series without taking derivatives? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that it's
$$ \frac{1}{2z} \frac{d}{d\xi} \frac{1}{1-2\xi+z^2}. $$
In fact we do have an expression for the latter fraction, although not really in closed form:
$$ \frac{1}{1-2\xi+z^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} U_n(\xi) z^n, $$
where $U_n$ is the [Chebyshev polynomial of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Definition). So we find that
$$ \frac{1}{(1-2\xi z+z^2)^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2}U_{n+1}'(\xi) z^n. $$
These are also a special case of the [ultraspherical/Gegenbauer polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gegenbauer_polynomials), which have generating function $(1-2\xi z +z^2)^{-\alpha}$.